# django-rest-auth + django-allauth + angular2

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to set up social registration (google, facebook, twitter) in my web application.
I use Django Rest Framework for backend and Angular2 for the frontend.
The standard registration works well with django-rest-auth.
I would like to set up the social auth part with django-allauth.
The social authentication scenario is :

- User clicks on "Login with Facebook" button
- He his redirected to Facebook's authorization page
- He accepts the Facebook authorization request
- He is redirected back to my web app while logged in

But first, I don't know how to redirect the user to the facebook authorization page. When I go to http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/facebook/, the form required data are "Access token" and "Code". But to set these data I have to get them from the facebook authorization page. Am I right?
How can I do it? How can I redirect the user to the social (facebook, google, twitter) authorization page ?

Answer (score 6):

Check out [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth). It's an alternative to django-allauth but easier to use. From your question, in order to enable facebook login, you need to capture the **access token** from the request made by angular2 to the facebook api and pass it to your backend.For your django backend, implement an api using [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). You can go about this in the following steps:

1. Register your application in [facebook developers page](https://developers.facebook.com).In the settings, leave the app domain empty and set the site url to *http://localhost:8000*. After successful setup, grab the **app secret** and **app id**. You will use it later on.
2. In your angular2 app index.html file, add the following script to your body.

`<script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=1622731728039944";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>`

3. npm install [ng2-facebook-sdk](https://github.com/zyramedia/ng2-facebook-sdk) and in th constructor for your component initialize the sdk

`    import {FacebookService, FacebookLoginResponse, FacebookInitParams} from 'ng2-facebook-sdk/dist';

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private fb: FacebookService) {
    let fbParams: FacebookInitParams = {
                                   appId: '123456789',
                                   xfbml: true,
                                   version: 'v2.6'
                                   };
    this.fb.init(fbParams);
  }
}
```

4. Add login function

`login() {
    this.fb.login({ scope: 'public_profile', return_scopes: true }).then(
        (response: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
            status = response['status'];
            var userId = response['authResponse'].userID;
            if (status == 'connected') {
                let access_token = response['authResponse']['accessToken'];
                localStorage.setItem('id_token', access_token);
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            }
        },
        (error: any) => console.error(error)
    );
}`

5. Then in every request you make to your backend, include the **access token** in the header. This will authenticate the user in your backend. 
   if the user doesn't exist, he will be created. e.g
   `var headers = new Headers();
       headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
       headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer facebook ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
       return this.http.post(this.url + '/api/images/edits/' + thumbId + '/', null, {
           headers: headers
       })
           .map(res => res.json());`
6. In your django backend, pip install [django-rest-framework-social-oauth2](https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2) and add these to your installed apps in **settings.py**.

   `INSTALLED_APPS = (
   ...
   'oauth2_provider',
   'social.apps.django_app.default',
   'rest_framework_social_oauth2',)`

   Add it to authentication class for restframework

`REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
    ),
}`

And set the authentication backends. Add facebook and any other social auth backend you need.

`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookAppOAuth2',
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
PROPRIETARY_BACKEND_NAME = 'Facebook'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'blablabla'`

7. In your view add the following decorator. This will be called on every request that requires authentication. Be sure to also add `permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)` to views that need to be protected.

`    from social.apps.django_app.utils import load_backend, load_strategy, psa
    from social.apps.django_app.views import _do_login
    from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

```
@psa('social:complete')
def auth_by_fb_token(request, backend):
    token = request.GET.get('access_token')
    user = request.backend.do_auth(token)
    if user:
        return user
```

Thus the access token you pass to the api will be used to authenticate and create a user in your backend. Redirection to the authentication page e.g facebook is done from the frontend since your backend is an api.